# How to get ADB logcat with specific tag in appium?

Tags: selenium, adb, appium, logcat

i want to get the ADB logcats for a specific tag(ex: testing_aws) through APPIUM. actually i have done this directly from console like follows

- I navigated to **/home/jagadeesh/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools**
- Then i ran this command`adb shell logcat | grep testing_aws` which is successfully given the data as expected
- Now i want to achieve same data through appium
- i have seen some solutions like `List<LogEntry> adbLogs
  =driver().manage().logs().get("logcat").filter(Level.ALL);` which it will give complete device logs, but i couldn't found a way to filter with specific tag (ex: testing_aws)
- So if there is a way to filter by tagname and get the output through appium please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first get all logs

```
List<LogEntry> logEntries = driver.manage().logs().get("logcat").filter(Level.ALL);
```

And then you can filter your log.

```
for (LogEntry logEntry : logEntries) {
    if (logEntry.getMessage().contains("testing_aws")) {
        System.out.println(logEntry.getMessage());
    }
}
```

If you want to add the filtered log in the file, you can do it like following:

```
List<LogEntry> logEntries = driver.manage().logs().get("logcat").filter(Level.ALL);
File logFile = new File("path to store file"+"filename"+".txt");
logFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();

PrintWriter log_file_writer = new PrintWriter(logFile);
for (LogEntry logEntry : logEntries) {
    if (logEntry.getMessage().contains("testing_aws")) {
        log_file_writer.println(logEntry);
    }
}
log_file_writer.flush();
```

Comment: you saved my day. Thanks.... it worked... One more thing i  want to know is can we clear this data before we perform any action??

Comment: do you mean file that we created?

Comment: No, actually i'm not storing into any file. Thing is for every action performed on my application i should get the event data(which we are currently getting as above solution that you given). But it will give the previous performed action data also.. so i want to clear the previous data and need current action data. Lets say we do `adb logcat -c` to clear the data right! so in the same way can we achieve with LogEntries?

Comment: you can run adb command in java to do so. use **Runtime.getRuntime().exec("adb logcat -c")**

Comment: i tried this, but not clearing the log 
`String[] temp = { "/home/jagadeesh/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb", "logcat", "-c" };`
`Runtime.getRuntime().exec(temp);`

Comment: I mean whenever i perform one action on my android app, then i need to get that action data only so that's y i need to clear the previous logs data. i have tried the above comment way and tried to executing same command `adb logcat -c` from **adb.sh** file then also not cleared.